# Add SVG object instead of file to LeafletJs

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I want to add a modified SVG object to a map instead of the original file.

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'zones.svg',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).then(function (value) {
        var svg = $(value);
        var width = svg.attr("width");
        var height = svg.attr("height");

    var zoneBounds = [[-height, 0], [0, width]];

    L.imageOverlay('zones.svg', zoneBounds, {
        opacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap);
});
```

Is there a way to override the original `imageOverlay()` method to accept an object instead of an URL of the file?
Or is there another built-in method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw some inspiration from the [`VideoOverlay` class](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/VideoOverlay.js) : extend `ImageOverlay`  and override `_initImage` to create a SVG node instead of an image.

Your class definition could look like this

```
var SVGOverlay = L.ImageOverlay.extend({
    options: {
    },

    _initImage: function () {
        var wasElementSupplied = this._url.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'svg';
        var svg = this._image = wasElementSupplied ? this._url : L.DomUtil.create('svg');
   }
});
```

and based on your example, you could set it up like this

```
var svgdomnode = svg.get(0); // your svg looks like a jQuery object, let's use a DOM node
var overlay = new SVGOverlay(svgdomnode, zoneBounds).addTo(mymap);
```

And a demo where an SVG node is inserted as a layer and modified when you click on a button.

```js
var SVGOverlay = L.ImageOverlay.extend({
    options: {
    },

    _initImage: function () {
        var wasElementSupplied = this._url.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'svg';
        var svg = this._image = wasElementSupplied ? this._url : L.DomUtil.create('svg');
   }
});

var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

var bounds = L.latLngBounds([[ 32, -130], [ 13, -100]]);
map.fitBounds(bounds);

var svg = document.getElementById('src').content.querySelector('svg');
var overlay = new SVGOverlay(svg, bounds).addTo(map);


var n = 0;
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'rect');
   
    rect.setAttribute('x', 20*n);
    rect.setAttribute('width', 20);
    rect.setAttribute('height', 20);
    rect.setAttribute('fill', '#0000ff');
    svg.appendChild(rect);
    
    n++;
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
button {position: absolute; left:100px; top: 0;z-index:10000}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>

<template id='src'>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width='100' height='100'>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30%" fill="green"/>
</svg>
</template>

<div id='map'></div>
<button>Click to add a square</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Release 1.5.0 includes this approach as layer type SVGOverlay.